# Auto pause and resume azure synapse analysis database

Tags: azure-synapse

Want to pause database on Saturday, Sunday and Monday morning want to resume automatically using any script or any option is to do ? or how?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a code what have you tried already. If nothing, than stackoverflow is not a good place for such questions..

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific feature for this task, but it is doable using a combination of techniques.o perform the Pause/Restart functionality, you can use the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).

**Recurrence Scheduling**

I recommend Logic Apps which has a robust recurrence trigger. You will most likely need to run it daily but you can specify the hour(s). To only continue on specific days, you'll need to add some additional processing to parse the DayOfWeek from the run time:

[image]

```
dayOfWeek(convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Eastern Standard Time'))
```

**Get Bearer Token**

In this example, I'm using a Service Principle to authenticate, and Azure Key Vault to store the relevant secrets:

[image]

**Check the Status of the Resource**

The next step is to check the status of the Data Warehouse: if it is already Paused, we only want to attempt to pause it if the status is "Online". To do this, we'll call the API again, this time passing the Bearer Token we acquired above:

[image]

In this example I'm using Variables instead of Key Vault to demonstrate different approaches.

We'll use the StatusCode property of the previous operation to make this determination:

[image]

**Check if there are any running Jobs**

If the Data Warehouse's Status is "Online", the next thing to check is whether or not there are any active processes. We accomplish this by running a query on the Data Warehouse itself:

[image]

We'll then capture the results in a variable and use that in another Condition activity:

[image]

```
body('Get_Ops_Count')?['resultsets']['Table1'][0]['OpsCount']
```

**Issue the Pause Command**

If there are no active jobs, we are free to finally issue the Pause command. Once again, we'll leverage the REST API using the Bearer Token we acquired previously:

[image]

**Restarting the Data Warehouse**

The Restart process is very similar, only without the need to check for active processes, so you should be able to extrapolate that from this example. To restart the Data Warehouse, the REST endpoint is "resume" instead of "pause".